# How to drag and drop images not in bundle in SwiftUI (macOS)

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to implement drag and drop in SwiftUI on macOS where I can either generate images programmatically and have them appear in the view as draggable items or load images from Assets.xcassets for the same purpose. I am basing my code off of [this](https://swiftui-lab.com/drag-drop-with-swiftui/). I tried referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60831260/swiftui-drag-and-drop-files) but I couldn't get it to work.

I got the image displaying fine, but since I am referencing the image itself, there is no URL I can return for the drag and drop API (see below):

```
//Value of type 'ContentView.DragableImage' has no member 'url' so I cannot use this
.onDrag { return NSItemProvider(object: self.url as NSURL) }
```

Here is the code. I have pointed things out via comments in the code:

```
import SwiftUI

let img1url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "grapes", withExtension: "png") // < -- CAN pass this in because it is by url
let img2url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "banana", withExtension: "png")
let img3url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "peach", withExtension: "png")
let img4url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "kiwi", withExtension: "png")

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack {
                //DragableImage(url: img1url!)
                //DragableImage(url: img3url!)

                DragableImage()
                DragableImage()
            }

            VStack {
                  //DragableImage(url: img2url!)
                 // DragableImage(url: img4url!)

               DragableImage()
               DragableImage()
            }

            DroppableArea()
        }.padding(40)
    }

    struct DragableImage: View {
        //let url: URL

        var body: some View {
            Image("grapes") //<--- Takes in image without url fine
           //Image(nsImage: NSImage(byReferencing: url)) //<--- Taking in image by URL (I don't want that)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2))
                .padding(2)
                .overlay(Circle().strokeBorder(Color.black.opacity(0.1)))
                .shadow(radius: 3)
                .padding(4)
                .onDrag { return NSItemProvider(object: self.url as NSURL) } //<--- MAIN ISSUE: "Value of type 'ContentView.DragableImage' has no member 'url'" (there is now no URL to reference the image by in the return)

        }
    }

    struct DroppableArea: View {
        @State private var imageUrls: [Int: URL] = [:]
        @State private var active = 0

        var body: some View {
            let dropDelegate = MyDropDelegate(imageUrls: $imageUrls, active: $active)

            return VStack {
                HStack {
                    GridCell(active: self.active == 1, url: imageUrls[1])

                    GridCell(active: self.active == 3, url: imageUrls[3])
                }

                HStack {
                    GridCell(active: self.active == 2, url: imageUrls[2])

                    GridCell(active: self.active == 4, url: imageUrls[4])
                }

            }
            .background(Rectangle().fill(Color.gray))
            .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
            .onDrop(of: ["public.file-url"], delegate: dropDelegate)

        }
    }

    struct GridCell: View {
        let active: Bool
        let url: URL?

        var body: some View {
            let img = Image(nsImage: url != nil ? NSImage(byReferencing: url!) : NSImage())
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 150, height: 150)

            return Rectangle()
                .fill(self.active ? Color.green : Color.clear)
                .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                .overlay(img)
        }
    }

    struct MyDropDelegate: DropDelegate {
        @Binding var imageUrls: [Int: URL]
        @Binding var active: Int

        func validateDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
            return info.hasItemsConforming(to: ["public.file-url"])
        }

        func dropEntered(info: DropInfo) {
            NSSound(named: "Morse")?.play()
        }

        func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
            NSSound(named: "Submarine")?.play()

            let gridPosition = getGridPosition(location: info.location)
            self.active = gridPosition

            if let item = info.itemProviders(for: ["public.file-url"]).first {
                item.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: "public.file-url", options: nil) { (urlData, error) in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        if let urlData = urlData as? Data {
                            self.imageUrls[gridPosition] = NSURL(absoluteURLWithDataRepresentation: urlData, relativeTo: nil) as URL
                        }
                    }
                }

                return true

            } else {
                return false
            }

        }

        func dropUpdated(info: DropInfo) -> DropProposal? {
            self.active = getGridPosition(location: info.location)

            return nil
        }

        func dropExited(info: DropInfo) {
            self.active = 0
        }

        func getGridPosition(location: CGPoint) -> Int {
            if location.x > 150 && location.y > 150 {
                return 4
            } else if location.x > 150 && location.y < 150 {
                return 3
            } else if location.x < 150 && location.y > 150 {
                return 2
            } else if location.x < 150 && location.y < 150 {
                return 1
            } else {
                return 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

I have also tried the following with far more success. It highlights upon image drag but on drop it will not show up:

```
import SwiftUI

let image1 = NSImage(named: "green")!
let image2 = NSImage(named: "blue")!

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack {
                DragableImage(image: image1)
                DragableImage(image: image2)
            }

            VStack {
               DragableImage(image: image1)
               DragableImage(image: image2)
            }

            DroppableArea()
        }.padding(40)
    }

    struct DragableImage: View {
        @State var image: NSImage
        @State private var dragOver = false

        var body: some View {
            Image(nsImage: image)
                .onDrop(of: ["public.file-url"], isTargeted: $dragOver) { providers -> Bool in
                    providers.first?.loadDataRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: "public.file-url", completionHandler: { (data, error) in
                        if let data = data, let path = NSString(data: data, encoding: 4), let url = URL(string: path as String) {
                            let imageLocal = NSImage(contentsOf: url)
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.image = imageLocal!
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    return true
                }
                .onDrag {
                    let data = self.image.tiffRepresentation
                    let provider = NSItemProvider(item: data as NSSecureCoding?, typeIdentifier: kUTTypeTIFF as String)
                    provider.previewImageHandler = { (handler, _, _) -> Void in
                        handler?(data as NSSecureCoding?, nil)
                    }
                    return provider
                }
                .border(dragOver ? Color.red : Color.clear)
        }
    }

    struct DroppableArea: View {
        @State private var imageUrls: [Int: URL] = [:]
        @State private var active = 0

        var body: some View {
            let dropDelegate = MyDropDelegate(imageUrls: $imageUrls, active: $active)

            return VStack {
                HStack {
                    GridCell(active: self.active == 1, url: imageUrls[1])

                    GridCell(active: self.active == 3, url: imageUrls[3])
                }

                HStack {
                    GridCell(active: self.active == 2, url: imageUrls[2])

                    GridCell(active: self.active == 4, url: imageUrls[4])
                }

            }
            .background(Rectangle().fill(Color.gray))
            .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
            .onDrop(of: ["public.file-url"], delegate: dropDelegate)

        }
    }

    struct GridCell: View {
        let active: Bool
        let url: URL?

        var body: some View {
            let img = Image(nsImage: url != nil ? NSImage(byReferencing: url!) : NSImage())
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 150, height: 150)

            return Rectangle()
                .fill(self.active ? Color.green : Color.clear)
                .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                .overlay(img)
        }
    }

    struct MyDropDelegate: DropDelegate {
        @Binding var imageUrls: [Int: URL]
        @Binding var active: Int

        func validateDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
            return info.hasItemsConforming(to: ["public.file-url"])
        }

        func dropEntered(info: DropInfo) {
            NSSound(named: "Morse")?.play()
        }

        func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
            NSSound(named: "Submarine")?.play()

            let gridPosition = getGridPosition(location: info.location)
            self.active = gridPosition

            if let item = info.itemProviders(for: ["public.file-url"]).first {
                item.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: "public.file-url", options: nil) { (urlData, error) in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        if let urlData = urlData as? Data {
                            self.imageUrls[gridPosition] = NSURL(absoluteURLWithDataRepresentation: urlData, relativeTo: nil) as URL
                        }
                    }
                }

                return true

            } else {
                return false
            }

        }

        func dropUpdated(info: DropInfo) -> DropProposal? {
            self.active = getGridPosition(location: info.location)

            return nil
        }

        func dropExited(info: DropInfo) {
            self.active = 0
        }

        func getGridPosition(location: CGPoint) -> Int {
            if location.x > 150 && location.y > 150 {
                return 4
            } else if location.x > 150 && location.y < 150 {
                return 3
            } else if location.x < 150 && location.y > 150 {
                return 2
            } else if location.x < 150 && location.y < 150 {
                return 1
            } else {
                return 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is almost the same as in references questions, the key is to use `NSImage` as model, instead of `Image` directly, to have ability to have access to image data to work with `NSItemProvider`:

```
struct DragableImage: View {
    var image = NSImage(named: "grapes")

    var body: some View {
        Image(nsImage: image ?? NSImage())
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2))
            .padding(2)
            .overlay(Circle().strokeBorder(Color.black.opacity(0.1)))
            .shadow(radius: 3)
            .padding(4)
            .onDrag {
                let data = self.image?.tiffRepresentation
                let provider = NSItemProvider(item: data as NSSecureCoding?, typeIdentifier: kUTTypeTIFF as String)
                provider.previewImageHandler = { (handler, _, _) -> Void in
                    handler?(data as NSSecureCoding?, nil)
                }
                return provider
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Only problem is that the draggable images (green and blue) will not show up on drop (nor does it even play the sounds from dropEntered or performDrop

Comment: (The image never gets added to DroppableArea)