# SwiftUI: How to drag and drop item in list into another item in same(another) list

Tags: swift, listview, drag-and-drop, swiftui

I am new to swift ui and i am building a kind of filemanager view
A have 2 lists (folders list and files list).
How can I move file item from files list into folder in folder list and also move folder item from folders list into another folder.
I think screenshots should help you to understand my problem:
[Screenshot of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlPFw.png)

Note: I DO NOT want to reorder or move item between list.
I want to drag item over(into) folder and make call to my API.

```
List {
                    ForEach(self.filemanager.folders, id: \.self) { folder in
                        FolderItemView(folder: folder)
                            .listRowBackground(Color.white)
                            .onTapGesture(count: 2) {
                                if (!self.isEditable) {
                                    withAnimation {
                                        self.filemanager.openFolder(folder: folder)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            .onTapGesture(count: 1) {
                                if (!self.isEditable) {
                                    self.folderToViewDetails = folder
                                }
                            }
                            .onLongPressGesture {
                                withAnimation {
                                    self.isEditable.toggle()
                                }
                            }
                    }//.onMove(perform: onMove)
                    .onDelete(perform: onDeleteFolder)
                    .sheet(item: self.$folderToViewDetails) { item in
                        FolderDetailedView(
                            folder: item,
                            filemanager: self.filemanager
                        )
                            .environmentObject(self.filemanager.appSettings)
                            .padding(.top, 16)
                    }
                    ForEach(self.filemanager.files, id: \.self) { file in
                        FileItemView(file: file)
                            .listRowBackground(Color.white)
                            .onTapGesture() {
                                if (!self.isEditable) {
                                    self.fileToViewDetails = file
                                }
                            }
                            .onLongPressGesture {
                                withAnimation {
                                    self.isEditable.toggle()
                                }
                            }
                    }//.onMove(perform: onMove)
                    .onDelete(perform: onDeleteFile)
                    .sheet(item: self.$fileToViewDetails) { item in
                        FileDetailedView(
                            file: item,
                            filemanager: self.filemanager
                        )
                            .environmentObject(self.filemanager.appSettings)
                            .padding(.top, 16)
                    }
                }.environment(\.editMode, isEditable ? .constant(.active) : .constant(.inactive))
```

Comment: This [SwiftUI Drag and Drop files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60832686/12299030) can be helpful.