# SwiftUI: Cannot make performDrop work with UTType

Tags: swift, swiftui, drag-and-drop

I am trying to implement a basic drop functionality that takes a text file, and dumps its content to a `text` variable. I am trying to make following code work:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

struct FileDropDelegate: DropDelegate {
    @StateObject var textInfo: TextInfo
    
    let contentTypes: [UTType] = [.text, .plainText, .utf8PlainText, .utf16PlainText, .utf8TabSeparatedText, .utf16ExternalPlainText, .commaSeparatedText, .rtf, .rtfd, .xml, .xmlPropertyList]
    
    func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
        if let item = info.itemProviders(for: contentTypes).first {
            item.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: contentTypes.description, options: nil) { (text, error) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if let data = text as? Data {
                        let string = String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)
                        textInfo.clear()
                        textInfo.selection.removeAll()
                        textInfo.text = string
                        textInfo.analyze()
                    } else {
                        return
                    }
                }
            }
        }        
        return true
    }
}
```

I am calling `.onDrop` like this:

```swift
.onDrop(of: [.text, .plainText, .utf8PlainText, .utf16PlainText, .utf8TabSeparatedText, .utf16ExternalPlainText, .commaSeparatedText, .rtf, .rtfd, .xml, .xmlPropertyList], delegate: FileDropDelegate(textInfo: textInfo))
```

It looks like `.loadItem` does not take a `UTType` argument, and I am not sure if `.description` is the sensible workaround to apply here.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/69325742/12299030?

Comment: It works when I use a string, like `"public.file-url"`, but I am interested in making it work with `UTType`. If what's written is correct in the above link, it's not meant to be used this way, but it is weird that `.infoProviders` accepts a `UTType` argument.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a bug. I can use the same [UTType] for NSOpenPanel's `allowedContentTypes` but the same [UTType] doesn't work for onDrop. Only UTType.fileURL seems to work.