# Why is there a "plus" icon at the top right corner of my view?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to implement the drag and drop feature to my `LazyHGridview`. When I try to drop the view on another view, a "plus" icon within a green circle is displayed at the top right corner of the view.

[image]

```
struct TestView: View {
var d: GridData
  @Binding var list: [GridData]
  @State private var dragOver = false
   
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text(String(d.id))
        .font(.headline)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
    }
    .frame(width: 160, height: 240)
    .background(colorPalette[d.id])
    .onDrag {
      let item = NSItemProvider(object: String(d.id) as NSString)
      item.suggestedName = String(d.id)
      return item
    }
    .onDrop(of: [UTType.text], isTargeted: $dragOver) { providers in
       
      return true
    }
    .border(Color(UIColor.label), width: dragOver ? 8 : 0)
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is managed by `DropProposal` drop operation and by default (if you do not provide explicit drop delegate) is `.copy` as documented, which adds '+' sign. By this you inform user that something will be duplicated.

```
/// Tells the delegate that a validated drop moved inside the modified view.
///
/// Use this method to return a drop proposal containing the operation the
/// delegate intends to perform at the drop ``DropInfo/location``. The
/// default implementation of this method returns `nil`, which tells the
/// drop to use the last valid returned value or else
/// ``DropOperation/copy``.
public func dropUpdated(info: DropInfo) -> DropProposal?
```

if you want to manage it explicitly then provide DropDelegate with implemented drop update as in below demo

```
func dropUpdated(info: DropInfo) -> DropProposal?
   // By this you inform user that something will be just relocated
   return DropProposal(operation: .move)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the normal user interface indicating that, at the point where your finger is at the moment, it is okay to drop the view you are dragging.

Comment: It is not displayed when I use the onDrop method with a DropDelegate like this: .onDrop(of: [UTType.text], delegate: DragRelocateDelegate2()). I don't think that it is the intended behavior.

Comment: Yes, it is displayed — when your finger dragging a view (preview) is over a target view that says it is okay to drop that type of data. If you make it possible to drag text and drop text _on the same view_ then you see the Plus as soon as you start dragging.