# How to Pass More than Just a String in NSItemProvider in SwiftUI Drag and Drop

Tags: swift, swiftui, nsitemprovider

I have reviewed some questions on Stack Overflow about drag and drop reorder with SwiftUI, and this one was particularly helpful: [SwiftUI | Using onDrag and onDrop to reorder Items within one single LazyGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62606907/swiftui-using-ondrag-and-ondrop-to-reorder-items-within-one-single-lazygrid)

I'm looking to expand this functionality where I drag something from one list of items to another in my SwifUI app. Let's say I have a `Task` list:

```
//TaskView.swift

ScrollView{
  VStack{
    ForEach(model.tasks, id: \.self){ task in
      Text(task.name)
        .onDrag{
          NSItemProvider(object: String(task.id) as NSString)
        }
    }
  }
}
```

...and I also have a `Project` list that I can drag a `Task` onto to move it to that project:

```
//ProjectView.swift

ScrollView{
  VStack{
    ForEach(model.projects, id: \.self){ project in
      Text(project.name)
        .onDrop(of: [UTType.text], delegate: ProjectDropDelegate(project: project))
    }
  }
}
```

The part I'm struggling with is in my `ProjectDropDelegate` where I'm trying to determine a couple things:

1. What kind of object is being dropped on me? (it must be a task)
2. If it's a task, what is its `id` so I can take action on it? (or, ideally, I'd get the whole `Task` object to work with)

I can't figure out how to make my `NSItemProvider` in `.onDrag` use anything other than a string and still work with my SwiftUI drag/drop functionality. For what it's worth, my `Task` and `Project` objects are Core Data classes.

How can I make `NSItemProvider` contain key-value pairs so I can pass a type identifier string like `myapp.task` (for #1 above) and an `id` (for #2)?

Comment: Good resources: https://exploringswift.com/blog/creating-a-nsitemprovider-for-custom-model-class-drag-drop-api (explains using `NSItemProviderReading`, `NSItemProviderWriting`), https://swiftui-lab.com/drag-drop-with-swiftui/ (shows using `itemProviders(for:)` in the drop delegate, where you'll want to check for your custom type that you've registered using the methods explained in the first link.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60832686/12299030?

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses. I've previously review all of those links and still found myself confused how my `Task` object can behave like an image (TIFF or `UIImage`) which seem to automatically be compatible with `UTType`. The Exploring Swift article may be what I need, but it's a bit complex, so it'll take me some time to digest it.

Answer (score 6):

After further investigation, I found a much simpler way to handle all this. I think `NSItemProvider` is a bit of a red herring if all you need to do is move data from one part of your app to another. Here's how I went about it and it seems to work great.

I alluded to `model.tasks` when I generated my list of tasks. Here's more about it:

```
class TaskModel: ObservableObject {
  static let shared = TaskModel()
  
  @Published var tasks = [Task]()
  var draggedTask: Task? //<-- I added this
  //...
}
```

I added a `draggedTask` optional to my model then I set it in my `onDrag` modifier like this:

```
Text(task.name)
  .onDrag{
    model.draggedTask = task
    NSItemProvider(object: NSString())
  }
```

I just pass an empty `String` object to `NSItemProvider` to satisfy its requirement for dragging something. Then in my `ProjectDropDelegate` I can have all the stuff I need, included setting a hovered UI state:

```
import SwiftUI
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

struct ProjectDropDelegate: DropDelegate {
  @Binding var hovered: Bool
  var project: Project?
  var modelTask = TaskModel.shared
  
  //MARK: Check before we start
  func validateDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
    //Allow the drop to begin with any String set as the NSItemProvider
    return info.hasItemsConforming(to: [UTType.text])
  }
  
  //MARK: Drop UI State
  func dropEntered(info: DropInfo) {
    //Show the hovered state if we have a draggedTask
    hovered = modelTask.draggedTask != nil
  }
  func dropExited(info: DropInfo) {
    hovered = false
  }
  
  //MARK: Drop and Save
  func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
    if let task = modelTask.draggedTask{
      //Save my task using modelTask...
      return true
    }else{
      return false
    }
  }
}
```

This is much simpler than I was initially making it.

Comment: Why do you have the "var project: Project?" in that DropDelegate? It doesn't look like it's doing anything.

Comment: I removed the code where it's used, but it's there to save changes to the `task` down in the `performDrop` function (I change the `project` property on the `task` object). 

Comment: This is a nice workaround but only works within your own app.

Answer (score 3):

Ran into the same problem. Something like this would work:

```
NSItemProvider(item: letter as NSString, typeIdentifier: "public.plain-text")
```

This would not work:

```
NSItemProvider(item: letter as NSString, typeIdentifier: "com.myapp.mytype")
```

Bug or feature? **Feature!**

The reason why the second, custom type identifier does not work is because this UTI has not been declared anywhere (yet).

The solution is to declare your custom type as UTI:

1. Open your project > target > Info > Exported Type Identifiers
2. Add an entry for your type:

   - Identifier: `com.myapp.mytype`
   - Conforms to: `public.data`

Now this will work (and you can hand in any object that supports `NSSecureCoding`):

```
NSItemProvider(item: letter as NSString, typeIdentifier: "com.myapp.mytype")
```

Build and run your app and reordering your list will now work!

Comment: In Apple documentation they explictly state that you shouldn't use "public" in your typeIdentifier, but some like "com.example.custom-type".

Comment: @SergioOcón-Cárdenas Thanks for the heads-up! I've updated the answer.

Comment: I don't know why you haven't been voted up. I struggle for a couple of hours figuring this out, almost had it, but your answer here is crystal clear. Works like a charm! No more dragging files to my nodes!