# SwiftUI macOS onDrop simple text always fails

Tags: macos, swiftui

Trying to implement a simple drag-drop of a text file:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var drag = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
            .onDrop(of: [.url], isTargeted: $drag) { (providers, location) in
                
                
                print("Can load", providers.first?.canLoadObject(ofClass: NSURL.self) == true) // Always false
                
                providers.first?.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.url.identifier, options: nil, completionHandler: { secureCoding, error in
                    
                    if let error = error {
                        print(error) // Cannot load representation of type ...
                    }
                    
                    if let item = secureCoding as? Data { // Always nil
                        print("got data")
                    }
                })
                
                return true
            }
    }
}
```

Tried to play with both the UTType of the file dropped (public.url,public.data) and the `loadItem(forTypeIdentifier)`.
Nothing I tried worked. Found similar questions, but they're not working and the answers looks out dated.

I have old Cocoa code, with `registerForDraggedTypes`, this looks much simpler, if it worked..

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60832686/12299030 - just tested still works.

Comment: Ok, changed `loadItem(forTypeIdentifier:)` to `loadDataRepresentation`, still getting errors "Cannot load representation of type public.file-url" (or any other type I tried)... What am I missing?

Comment: Ok, using the code (copy/paste) from  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60831260/swiftui-drag-and-drop-files/60832686#60832686  works. All come down to this, using `.onDrop(of: [.fileURL]`, not `.onDrop(of: [.url]`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just modified and tested with plain .txt file. Xcode 13.3 / macOS 12.3.1

```
    @State private var text = "Drop Here"
    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200).border(.red)
            .onDrop(of: ["public.file-url"], isTargeted: $dragOver) { providers -> Bool in
                providers.first?.loadDataRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: "public.file-url", completionHandler: { (data, error) in
                    if let data = data, let path = NSString(data: data, encoding: 4), let url = URL(string: path as String) {
                        if let value = try? String(contentsOf: url, encoding: .utf8) {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                 self.text = value
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
                return true
            }
```

*Note: I cannot remember exactly where but I met in Apple's documentation that we must use concrete UTTypes for specific use-cases instead of generic, ie. fileURL is really URL but for matching it must be specified exactly!

Comment: This also works `.onDrop(of: [.fileURL]`. Seems that `UTType.url` expect a remote URL and will not work when dragging files, need to use `UTType.fileURL`

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post my own answer, just to point out the pitfalls. Thanks to @Asperi, I got a working sample.

1. `.onDrop(of: [.fileURL]`, needs to be `UTType.fileURL` (or `public.file-url`), not `UTType.url`.
2. I was using `providers.first?.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier:...`, needs to be `loadDataRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier:...`
3. Reading the data:
   Using `let path = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)` works. The next step is important, I needed to use `URL(string:)`. not `URL(fileURLWithPath:)`
   Using `URL(fileURLWithPath:)` will produce something that looks like URL with secure scope.

Other minor notes:
Using `let path = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)` works, no need for `NNString`.
Using `UTType.fileURL` (and `UTType.fileURL.identifier` for `String`) also works, no need for hard coding `"public.file-url"`