# Load NSImage into Image(named:) in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swiftui

I have a MacOS app that I am rewriting in SwiftUI. I am completely new to SwiftUI.

I have an Image() and when I drag an image from the Desktop on to that image I want to load the dropped image into it. I am able to detect drop and I am able to switch out the images to show the cursor is hovering over the drop zone. But, what I don't understand is how can I take the file from the desktop and load it into the Image()?

I have the file's URL, I create an NSImage from the contentsOf but how do I get that NSImage into the Image(named:)?

"input" & "inputDropZone" are assets in the asset catalog

Is my approach wrong?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var sourceImage = "input"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
           Image(sourceImage)
                .frame(width: 200.0, height: 200.0)
                .onDrop(of: [UTType.fileURL.description], delegate: self)
        }
     }
 }

extension ContentView : DropDelegate {

    func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
        guard let itemProvider = info.itemProviders(for: [UTType.fileURL.description]).first else { return false }
        itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.fileURL.description) { item, error in
            guard let data = item as? Data, let url = URL(dataRepresentation: data, relativeTo: nil) else { return }

            if let image = NSImage(contentsOf: url) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    sourceImage = ? //How do I load an NSImage into an Image(named:)?
                }
            }
        }

        return true
    }
    
    func dropEntered(info: DropInfo) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            sourceImage = "inputDropZone"
        }
    }
    
    func dropExited(info: DropInfo) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            sourceImage = "input"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60832686/12299030?

Comment: You cannot *get that NSImage into the Image(named:)* because the API refers to images in the asset catalog which is immutable at runtime. You could declare the `@State` variable as `Image` and get the image with `Image(nsImage:`

Comment: Asperi, yes that worked perfectly. Thank You. Vadian, I believe you had said the same thing so, thank you. I swear I tried doing an NSImage() but wasn't getting it to work. Was I see if working it doesn't seem that difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by taking Asperi's & Vadian's suggestions. I combined Asperi's answer at:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60832686/12299030

into my own code so that I could use the delegate methods. This is the final working code:

```
import SwiftUI
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var sourceImage = NSImage(named: "input")
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
           Image(sourceImage)
                .frame(width: 200.0, height: 200.0)
                .onDrop(of: [UTType.fileURL.description], delegate: self)
        }
     }
 }


extension ContentView : DropDelegate {
    func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
        guard let providers = info.itemProviders(for: [UTType.fileURL.description]).first else { return false }
        providers.loadDataRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: "public.file-url", completionHandler: { (data, error) in
            if let data = data, let path = NSString(data: data, encoding: 4), let url = URL(string: path as String) {
                let image = NSImage(contentsOf: url)
                image?.size = CGSize(width: 200.0, height: 200.0)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.sourceImage = image
                }
            }
        })
        return true
    }
    
    func dropEntered(info: DropInfo) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            sourceImage = NSImage(named: "inputDropZone")
        }
    }
    
    func dropExited(info: DropInfo) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            sourceImage = NSImage(named: "input")
        }
    }
}
```